# How to rewrite this URL in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

How to rewrite the original URL with .htaccess?

example :

Original URL = **www.mydomain.com/en/specialroom.php**

rewrite to = **www.mydomain.com/en/roomspecial/**

Thanks before, best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/roomspecial/$ /en/specialroom.php [L]
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.